# If $G$ has an element of order $p$ and an element of order $q$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then the order of $G$ is a multiple of $pq$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If $G$ has an element of order $p$ and an element of order $q$, where
>   $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then the order of $G$ is a multiple of
>   $pq$

Here is how I am working out my proof:

Suppose $x,y \in G$ and let $|x|=p$ and $|y|=q$ where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes.

I am having trouble wording it and putting it together.

So the next thing, I wanna say is:

By Lagrange's theorem the order of $G$ is a multiple of $p$ and a multiple of $q$. Therefore, $G$ must be a multiple of $pq$.

However, it feels quite empty and missing something.

Comment: You need to use that they are prime.  For example if $|x|=6$ and $|y|=3$, then it may not be true that the order of $G$ is a multiple of $18$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126, by the way this is just a random example that doesn't relate to the problem since 6 isn't prime.

Comment: It's a counterexample in the case that $|x|$ and $|y|$ are not relatively prime.  But, your argument, as stated, would apply to the situation where they aren't relatively prime.  Thus your argument is lacking some detail.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126. Great thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, but you could add a little more detail, as below.

More generally, if $G$ has an element of order $m$ and an element of order $n$, then by Lagrange's theorem the order of $G$ is a multiple of both $m$ and $n$ and so is a multiple of $lcm(m,n)$. In particular, if $m$ and $n$ are coprime, then $lcm(m,n)=mn$, and the order of $G$ is a multiple of $mn$.

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then they are coprime and the result above holds.

Comment: Great! I added the details to my proof, thanks!